# Networking para cambiar el mundo un regex a la vez: Validación de correo electrónico en instituciones bancarias

Tags: discusión

Solicito orientación para conectar con algún influencer que incida en la validación de correo electrónicos en los sistemas de los bancos mexicanos, los cuales están globalizados.

Nota del autor: Si los bancos usan otra cosa diferente a regex, se aceptan la edición del título por la comunidad para sustituir `regex` por lo que corresponda siempre y cuando se incluya la referencia correspondiente en el cuerpo de esta pregunta.

Motivo:

Recién me encontré con que dos bancos mexicanos no aceptan direcciones válidas de correo electrónico, según entiendo las validaciones que están usando son demasiado estrictas

Ejemplos

1) Nombre de usuario de dos letras, como  `aa@c.mx`
2) Nombre de usuario con signo más (+), como en los alias de Gmail, G Suite como en `aa+b@c.mx`

Nota: Me parece que es obvio, pero por no dejar, aclaro que los casos son ficticios para fines ilustrativos. Casos reales a disposición de los interesados, vía conversación privada.

Lo anterior surge a raíz de al realizar dos trámites, apertura de cuenta de ahorro para un menor, y registro para envio de estado de cuenta por correo eléctronico en lugar de papel, me topé con que no pude usar mi dirección de correo electrónico y al realizar la investigación para publicar una pregunta al primer intento, me tope con

[What is the proper minimum length of an email address as defined by the IETF or the like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423195/what-is-the-proper-minimum-length-of-an-email-address-as-defined-by-the-ietf-or)

en el cual una de las respuestas incluye un enlace a

[I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/), así que mi "primera impresión" fue que los bancos están mal :)

Me pregunto si dicha conclusión está correcta de ser así que "algún día" se corrija y que ello surja de esta comunidad.

Otras publicaciones relacionadas:

- [The survey isn't accepting my email address: Validation blocks the `+`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341478/the-survey-isnt-accepting-my-email-address-validation-blocks-the) (via @fedorqui)

Comment: Lo de que no acepten el signo más `+` es una pena. Yo uso mucho el truco `micuenta+filtro@gmail.com` y rara vez se me permite usarlo.

Comment: Me animo a decir que el 99% de los formularios no aceptan direcciones válidas (según el [RFC 6854](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6854#section-3)), y el límite suele ser establecido por lo que el programador/la institución consideran normalmente aceptado. Los bancos no están mal (al menos no en este aspecto). Al momento de elegir esas reglas suelen tomar la decisión consciente de no aceptar algunas (pocas) direcciones válidas con el fin de evitar muchas posibles direcciones inválidas. Algo de esto se discutió en http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/142/127 ... Pero ¿por qué esta publicación en meta?

Comment: @fedorqui ni siquiera SO lo acepta en (al menos algunos) de sus formularios :\ Por ejemplo, en la [encuesta a desarrolladores](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/The-2017-Stack-Overflow-Developer-Survey-is-Now-Live/?cb=1)

Comment: @Mariano ya hay quien lo reportó como bug: [The survey isn't accepting my email address: Validation blocks the `+`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341478/1983854)

Comment: @Mariano: En relación a la razón de poner la publicación en meta, en primer lugar porque según entiendo el solicitar orientación para conectar con un influencer es offtopic en el sitio principal, en segundo lugar, porque  es parte de mi investigación para publicar una "buena pregunta" :)

Comment: No sabía que tampoco se podía en SO... que conste que mi publicación fue antes que el reporte referido en el comentario de fedorqui :P

Comment: @Rubén entiendo, pero mi pregunta apuntaba a esto: supongamos que alguien puede generarte el contacto, entonces ¿qué? ¿cuál sería la  propuesta? ¿qué se estaría cambiando del mundo y cómo participaría la comunidad de SOes? Además, ¿qué te hace pensar que un banco podría estar interesado en validar un e-mail según el RFC o más aún por qué estás asumiendo que existe un regex que siga el RFC y sea viable?

Comment: @Mariano: La inclusión de regex en el título es una libertad que me he tomado como autor porque asumí que tu comentario acerca de por aque había realizado la pregunta implicaba que debía ir en el sitio principal. Ya con tu último comentario me queda claro a que te refieres. Ya tengo pensado agregar algunas cosas que podría responder parcialmente algunos de tus cuestionamientos, los cuales te agradezco. Espero poder encontrar el tiempo para agregarlos a la pregunta durante el fin de semana.

Comment: @Rubén no quise cuestionarte, sino más bien estaba intentando buscar una solución... Pero pensé en lo siguiente: "*si tengo un contacto con el CIO de un banco, ¿los puedo contactar?*", y la respuesta que se me ocurrió fue  "*no puedo decirle a mi contacto que hable con alguien sin siquiera saber el motivo*"... Entonces, si alguien tiene ese contacto, esperaría que le quede claro también... En fin, era un intento de ayudarte.

Comment: @Mariano: Para mí el término "cuestionar" es super positivo.  La primera definición que ofrece la RAE es "Controvertir un punto dudoso, proponiendo las razones, pruebas y fundamentos de una y otra parte.". El escuchar/leer cuestionamientos sobre mis palabras y acciones me retroalimenta y me ayuda de muchas formas, ya hasta tengo ganas de publicar algo al respecto; cuando suceda se los comparto.

Comment: @Rubén genial... Me alegra que se haya entendido así (a veces un comentario corto puede sonar un tanto rudo)